# Executing *.exe file from mounted ISO. No permissions

Tags: wine, iso

I'm trying to run *.exe file from ISO that I've mounted, but I can't. Wine says "Access denied".

[image]

Any ideas how to receive permission to run this file?

Comment: Can you provide the full error (if you are trying to run it from a terminal)? Also have you tried to copy the files you mounted to some directory in your pc and run it then?

Comment: It seems like the pic has very low resoultion. The statement on the screen says: "the permissions could not be determined"

Comment: @Salem the iso file is on my desktop, I opened it using "Archive Mounter"

Comment: Can you try running the program from the terminal instead of right click then open?  

wine vs_ultimate.exe

Comment: You can try to add execute permission to the exe file, but i don't know if wine uses it: `chmod +x /path/to/file.exe`. Also from the screenshot it seems you are trying to install Visual Studio. From [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892) it seems it doesn't work well under Wine...

Comment: It isn't related to topic, but there is no way currently to run VS at least 2012 using WINE: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892

Comment: @Houssem how can I get the path in files explorer? I used to use ctrl+l in older versions of Ubuntu, but in 14.04 it doesn't work :P

Comment: @enedil is there any chance to run it on Ubuntu in future? Is it only sth like bug in wine or microsoft introduced some restrictions?